# Is there a way to add values in XML layouts?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to do something like:

```
android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize + 20dp"
```

Do I have to do this programatically when I create my `View`, or is there some XML notation I can use?

Comment: I guess you need JAVA for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xml layout is NOT like html which you can inject tags into. your xml layout will be inflated by your system to android View object. the xml file will nomore be used after creation.
but you can do it in your activity class

```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout); // set your layout

    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)getWindow().getDecorView();
    // this will get the main view which you layout is child of;
    // this will get the parent object of your layout not the layout itself;
    vg.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom); // set your padding


    /// you can also use
    ViewGroup vg1 = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.your containter);
    vg1.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);


}
```

then about ?attr:actionbarSize, I don't know how to get it in java class